# How to reduce the value of an array key if there are missing values

Tags: php

Please forgive my title because I have no idea how to explain it.

Basically, I have arrays that can have up to 40 keys (all coincidentally with a unique value of 1-40).

All keys need to retain its position. But the values need to be renumbered from "1" to "the total number of keys within the array" but retaining its relative position.)

This array:

```
$a = array(1,5,16,7,4)
```

would be converted to a new array of:

```
$b = array(1,3,5,4,2)
```

*Relative - As you can see, 16 changes to 5, but is still the highest number within the array, with 7 changing to 4 and so on.

This has been driving me nuts all day. I've used while loops and all sorts of things, and I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your (most promising) attempts? As it is currently written, the question could be interpreted "please write code for me" instead of "please help me understand how I can do this myself"

Comment: `min` and `max` give you the highest and lowest values in the array, `count` will tell you how many elements are in the array... do the maths (oh, and even if the positions of the elements in the array can't change, there's nothing stopping you from creating a _copy_, is there?)

Comment: Thanks Elias - that's pretty much what I was trying to do, use min, max and count, but the entire thing was a shambles. It's far too over-complicated that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array(1,5,16,7,4);
$b = $a;
sort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($b as $kb => $vb){
    foreach($a as $ka => $va){
        if($vb === $va)
            $c[] = $ka+1;
    }
}
//$c will contain the result you are asking
print_r($c);
```

Comment: No need to maintain the key assoc in this example. I am looping the array before and after sort, compare to get the same val, and just keep the after sort key to a $c array. I suppose it is not the most efficient way to do this

Comment: Excellent Stavros! Thank you!